# Changed Lion Server's host name and now unable to browse to that site

Tags: macos, osx-server

(Without thinking much) I set up my Mac mini server and used an actual domain name I use as the computer's host name.

I've since changed the host name to something that isn't an actual website, but I'm unable to navigate to the original hostname/domain. I've tried *changeip* in the terminal as well, as well as flushed DNS in case it was cached there as well.

How do I get Lion to reach out to the WWW to find this domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by removing this from */etc/named.conf*

I'm now able to navigate to example.com.

```
zone "example.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "db.example.com";
    allow-transfer {
        none;
    };
    allow-update {
        none;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In terminal enter:

```
hostname -fs
```

That will tell you the hostname of your machine. You may need to edit your hosts file:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

If your machine is listed in the there simply remove it and then control-w to save the change.

Comment: The hosts file only contains the expected references to localhost — 127.0.0.1 etc — while hostname shows the current hostname. Still no luck...